# Visual Basic 6 cmd.exe compilation - popping windows

Tags: java, vb6, cmd

I'm writing java code that compiles various VB6 projects. I make a cmd.exe Process Builder with the right commands and execute it. My problem is that the projects I compile open pop up windows that need to be closed manually, connected with used API's + compile errors. Is there a way to make those windows not pop up or at least close them right away automatically, either by way of java code or maybe a special VB6.EXE command in the cmd prompt?

EDIT: the code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder;
builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c",
          "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\VB98\" && VB6.EXE /m "
          + project.getPathToProject() + " /outdir " + outputPath + " && exit");
File outputDir = new File(outputPath);
if (!outputDir.exists()) {
    outputDir.mkdirs();
}
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while (true) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}

p.waitFor();
int exit = p.exitValue();
```

**UPDATE:** the /out command helps with the error windows but I still get ComponentOne 'about' windows during compilation (an API used in the projects I presume).

Comment: What is the code you use? You shouldn't need to spawn `cmd` at all; you should be able to call the compiler directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open a command prompt and navigate to the folder, then run "VB6 /?", you will see a popup window that shows the command line arguments you can use.

Of interest to you is the /out parameter.  According to the documentation:

> /out filename    -   Specifies a file to receive errors when you build
>   using /m or /runexit.  If you do not use /out, command line build
>   errors are displayed in a message box.

Comment: +1. Also if you possibly can, **fix the code** so you don't get the warnings & errors

Comment: Thank you this does help with the error windows but the API windows opened by VB6.EXE still prevail, and the worst thing is that it stops the compilation process until closed. To elaborate more it's a ComponentOne 'about' window, it doesn't spawn it's own process.
@MarkJ It's not about the VB6 code creating errors because I make them intentionally, I want the windows to not show even if the compilation fails.

Comment: Oh good, I read the original question to mean that you were always getting some compilation warnings that you were ignoring. A ComponentOne about box during compilation? Could it be a warning from the ComponentOne product that you are using a demo version?? Is the product properly installed on the build server?

Comment: Yes it was a pop up with the trial version, I decided that registering solves my problem. Thanks for help @G Mastros and @MarkJ